# Adding export-to-csv option onto Highcharts chart as a client user?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export-to-csv

While there is documentation on this issue I am finding myself going through a high amount of grief trying to understand what needs to be done to achieve what I want.

I'm a user with no privileges to a website that has Highcharts charts that I want to export into a csv. Highcharts from this url and similar webpages in the domain are what I want to export:

https://www.racingandsports.com.au/horse/taiyoo-660888-tab-rating

Specifically I want the first chart. As you can see it has a drop down menu which allows the image to be printed, and downloaded as a jpeg, png, pdf and svg. I've seen JSFiddle code snippets that the drop down menu to have an export to csv option. I have tried running Greasemonkey with scripts as well as editing through the inspect element menus on a web browser. I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu.

Is this achievable as a client or if I want to get this data should I go about coding my own Python with beautifulsoup program to scrape it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process will be little tricky, because of fact that site uses Highcharts **v4.0.4**, and the export to CSV is available from **v5.0.11**, but I can't say it's not possible to do that.

You need to manually add the body of `export-data.js` Highcharts module from your browser developer console, but first you need to extend Highcharts by some functions and parameters which are necessary to run that module. I will try to describe the process step by step, and as clear as I can.

1. Open the site,
2. Open the developer console of your browser
3. Paste the code below in your console, and press Enter key:

   ```
   Highcharts.win = window;
   Highcharts.inArray = function(item, arr, fromIndex) {
     return (
       Highcharts.indexOfPolyfill ||
       Array.prototype.indexOf
     ).call(arr, item, fromIndex);
   };
   Highcharts.find = function(arr, fn) {
     var i,
     length = arr.length;

     for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       if (fn(arr[i], i)) {
         return arr[i];
       }
     }
   };
   ```
4. Then, just open the https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.11/modules/export-data.src.js , copy whole code, paste it in the console and run it.

Now you should be able to download the CSV by opening the dropdown menu and clicking first "undefined" on the list from the top.

I tested it and it's working.

Comment: Good grief, you're a genius lad! Works very well. Returns the distance, rating, average rating and winner. I'm sure I could tinker around with the code provided to get the other variables but you've provided exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Of course you can `update` all chart by developer console, because Highcharts library is available globally. All charts are in `Highcharts.charts`array.